# 2D table conversion for example: y = f(x1,x2) => x1 = f(y, x2)

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab

The problem I need to resolve is to convert 2D look-up table.

[image]

This table could be defined as an array

```
Table = [ -54 97 ... 362;
          -60 114 ... 425;
          ...
          -111 31 ... 277;]

x1 = [0 20 ... 100]
x2 = [800 1200 ... 4800].
```

So given any `x1`, `x2` within the arrange, `y = f(x1,x2)` defined by the above table could give a `y` value.

Now, I need to get `x1` given `y` and `x2`. That is, given rpm and `y` value, figure out appropriate `x1`. for example, 800 rpm and 97, gives value 20%. If it is 800 and 107, returns 28.3%.

Either Matlab or Python could be used.

Comment: Why the 25% with `x2=800` and `y=107` ?

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. It shall be 28.3% with x2=800 and y=107. I gave 25% as a guess when defining the question.

Answer (score 3):

In Matlab:

My other answer assumed the most general case where the value for the RPM could be anything in the range of 800 to 4800. However, if you're certain that your chosen value will be one of the rows, you need only consider the values in that row:

```matlab
Percent = [0 20 30 40 ... 90 100];
RPM = [800; 1200; 1400; ... 4400; 4800];
Table = [ -54 97 ... 362;
          -60 114 ... 425;
          ...
          -111 31 ... 277;]
x2 = 800;
y = 107;

RPM_id = find(RPM == x2,1);
Table_row = Table(RPM_id,:);
x1 = interp1(Table_row,Percent,y)
```

Which once again results in

```matlab
x1 =
   28.3333
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid multiple construction of interpolation, I propose to use [`griddedInterpolant`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant.html) so that all interpolants are built once and then you can query ad libitum.

Note that you should think about interpolation, that is what numerical scheme you want to use to compute values that do not belong to the initial table (like (800;107) in the OP). Basic (and default) scheme is linear interpolation; with your table (not uniform), higher order interpolation schemes may be amongst 'makima' and 'spline'. See the doc for more info about all of this.

Code for building the interpolant is as follows, assuming that the whole table is stored in variable `T`:

```matlab
rpm = [800 1200 1400 1600:400:4800];
N = [0 20:10:100];
[g_rpm, g_N] = meshgrid(rpm, N);
G = griddedInterpolant(rpm, N ,T);
```

Add a fourth parameter to specify the interpolation scheme (eg `'makima'`).

Then, to find the desired value, you can build your own function as follows:

```matlab
F = @(r, t) fminsearch(@(x) abs(t-G(r,x)), 50);
```

50 is a priori startint value; you must refine it in case `T` is not montonic.

On the inputs in the OP:

`F(800, 97)` gives 20

`F(800, 107)` gives 28.333 (with linear interpolation, 28.224 with makima interpolation and 26.898 with spline interpolation)

**Enhancement**

In the case you want to vectorize the computation, you can do this by enclosing the body of function `F` with `arrayfun`:

```matlab
F = @(R,T) arrayfun(@(r,t) fminsearch(@(x) abs(t-G(r,x)), 25), R, T);
```

So now you can put several couple of inputs at once like this:

```matlab
F([800 2000],[100 100])

ans =

       21.966       15.564
```

Comment: `griddedInterpolant` is a great tool when you're going to doing multiple evaluations of a large data set. But its use is not as clear as any of the `interp` commands. For the size of the table here, you'd be hard-pressed to see the difference in execution time unless it's repeatedly accessed thousands of times. For a larger data set, the advantage in speed outweighs the added complexity. For anyone reading this in the future looking to interpolate irregular data, the related function TriScatteredInterp is also very useful.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab:

The general case is where x2 value is not an element of the RPM vector. If it is sure to be so, you can convert the below 2D interpolation into a 1D interpolation. But for the general case you can guess an x1, interpolate (x1,x2) into your table and see if the resultant value equals your y value.

```matlab
Percent = [0 20 30 40 ... 90 100];
RPM = [800; 1200; 1400; ... 4400; 4800];
Table = [ -54 97 ... 362;
          -60 114 ... 425;
          ...
          -111 31 ... 277;]


x2 = 800;
y = 107;

% we square the difference since we want the error to be > 0
F = @(s) (interp2(Percent, RPM, Table,s,x2) - y).^2; 

x1 = fminbnd(@(x) F(x),0,100)
```

Which results in

```matlab
x1 =
   28.3333
```

Edit: A previous version of this solution was based on evenly-distributed values for percents. There is no column for 10% so the answer for the example was wrong. The solution has been updated to reflect the correct percentages.

Comment: Hello, Wick, very interesting idea. I'm evaluating it carefully. However, it is counter-intuitive to me that the result is 18.33. This is because of @800rpm, according to the table, y at107 N.m is between 20% and 30%. why the return from the program is less than 20%?

Comment: My mistake. My previous solution didn't take into account the unevenly-spaced percentages. If you typed in Percent = [0 10 20 ...] you'd have gotten 18%. The solution has been edited to reflect that.